# two level ng-options nested object

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: Using only `ng-options` as much as possible.

How the data looks like:

```
vm.category = [
    0: {
        label: 'Label A',
        children: [
            {
                label: 'Label A.1',
                value: 'labelA1',
            }
        ]
    }

    1: {},
    2: {}
]
```

How it will look like in the HTML. `Expected HTML`

```
<select>
    <optionGroup> Label A </optionGroup>
        <option value="labelA1"> Label A.1 </option>
        <option value="labelA2"> Label A.2 </option>
    <optionGroup> Label B </optionGroup>
        <option  value="labelB1"> Label B.1 </option>
</select>
```

How to achieve this without changing the data structure as much as possible?

I tried `ng-options="category.children.label group by category.label for category in vm.categoryTree"`. But the output is

```
<select>
    <optionGroup> Label A </optionGroup>
        <option> undefined  </option>
    <optionGroup> Label B </optionGroup>
        <option> undefined </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you want the `ng-model` to be?

Comment: I'm not really touching the `ng-model`.

Comment: What I mean is what do you want to assign on selection?

Comment: Updated `Expected HTML`.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to map the data to a format more easily used by the `ng-options` *"group by"* expression

```js
angular.module('so', []).controller('snippet', function() {
  this.categoru = [{"label":"Label A","children":[{"label":"Label A.1","value":"labelA1"}]},{"label":"Label B","children":[{"label":"Label B.1","value":"labelB1"}]}];

  this.options = this.categoru.reduce((flat, group) => {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(flat, group.children.map(child => {
      return Object.assign({
        parent: group.label
      }, child);
    }));
    return flat;
  }, []);
  console.log(this.options);
});
```

```html
<form ng-app="so" ng-controller="snippet as vm">
  <select ng-model="vm.selected" 
          ng-options="opt.label group by opt.parent for opt in vm.options track by opt.value">
  </select>
  <pre>vm.selected = {{vm.selected | json }}</pre>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The example code should show the actual select component to become more convincing though...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
 <select ng-model='theModel' ng-change="display(theModel)">
        <optgroup ng-repeat='group in collection' label="{{group.Name}}">
        <option ng-repeat='veh in group.Fields' value='{{group.Name}}::{{veh.Name}}'>{{veh.Name}}</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hs6nplQhvOaMSz2rDGHE?p=preview)**

Comment: I've also read about using `ng-repeat` but wouldn't it be possible to just use `ng-options`?

Comment: @DevTestAcct if you're just after HTML, then you should use this solution as `ng-options` will not produce the `value` attributes you want